# Unsure of Where to Begin (See Image)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image: The Problem]

Any advice on where to begin? (What theorems to look up or links to useful pages etc.) Not looking for direct answer just a  little guidance.

Comment: What specifically are you unsure about?  $S$ is the set of all functions with domain $\{a,b,c\}$ and codomain $\{1,2,\dots,n+1\}$ such that $f(a)<f(c)$ and $f(b)<f(c)$.  $S_1$ in problem1 is the set of functions from $S$ such that $f(c)=2$ specifically.

Comment: Is this related to any theorem (Mean Value Theorem) or keywords i can google for help on this problem.

Comment: Sorry, the title was a bit misleading.

Comment: This should be a straightforward multiplication principle or stars and bars question from enumerative combinatorics.  Choose what $f(a)$ is.  Choose what $f(b)$ is...

Comment: So for the first part would f(a) = 1 and f(b) = 1 and |S1| = 3?

Comment: Also, for the second part is i any number between 1 and n including 1 and n?

Comment: No, $|S_1|$ is not equal to $3$, $f(a)=1$ is not the only available choice, how many choices do you have?  $f(b)=1$ is not the only available choice, how many choices do you have?  What does this imply that multiplication principle will tell you about the size of $|S_1|$?  Yes `<=` is shorthand for $\leq$ when you don't have access to proper symbols like you do when you have $\LaTeX$...

Comment: But if f(a) and f(b) have to be less than two then they both have to equal to 1, is that not the case?

Comment: Fair enough, I read wrong, but that still will imply that $|S_1|$ is not equal to $3$...

Comment: Would the |S1| = 1 because each member has ((a,f(a)), (b,(f(b)), and (c,(f(c)))

Comment: And would |Si| = i^2 by the multiplication principle?

Comment: You tell me, you asked for "*just a little guidance*"

Comment: Fair enough, can you at least confirm that each member of the set S, Si, T1, T2, T3 has three members ((a,f(a)), (b,(f(b)), and (c,(f(c)))?

Comment: Okay so I think i made it to the last part but have gotten stuck. I know that if f(c) = n there are n-1 options for f(b) and if f(b) = n - 1 then there are n-2 options for f(a) but I don't know how to account for when n - 1 = 1?

Answer (score 0):

As yo do not want direct answer. here is some guidance. Explain everything in words. Let A be the set having 3 persons, Alice, Bob and Charlie.
Assume you are asked to pay each of them some varying amount \$1 to \$(n+1). (no coins only whole dollars).

The set S represents various ways of paying such that Charlie gets more than Alice as well as Bob. S1 says further that Charlie get \$2.
You are asked to find how many ways of paying is possible (assume you have infinite source of funds!)

Now go ahead.

Comment: For the third and fourth part can f(c) be any value in B?

Comment: I have interpreted two sets; you can try the others; assume nothing more than what is given in symbols.